# Android Unit Testing with Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, android-mvvm

I have a ViewModel in which there is a method which has the following line of code:

```
billDate.set(!TextUtils.isEmpty(SampleApp.getInstance().getAccountManager().getDueDate()) ?
            String.format(SampleApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.due),
                    SampleApp.getInstance().getAccountManager().getBillingDueDate()) :
            SampleApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.missing_due_date));
```

I have a test class using Mockito to test the different methods in ViewModel. But it is failing with `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
String.format(SampleApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.due),
```

Below is the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2547)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
```

While running a test case, I see the log showing some error related to `Pattern`
Can somebody suggest, how to test the `String.format()` method?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @GiorgioAntonioli I have pasted the log

Comment: Can you add the related testcase?

Comment: Default implementation of getString returns null, you can mock it or use wrapper interface such as StringProvider.

Comment: Please post the testcase along with the mocked class @Lavanya

Comment: Either your due string is not present in current module or you are getting null context.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule getString(R.string.due) is coming as null. I have tried hard coding it in my ViewModel java class and the test case passed. But, how do I fix this?

Comment: try something like this `SampleApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(...)`

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/195-android-unit-testing-with-mockito

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not be importing android view packages into your ViewModel. So skip using things like `TextUtils` inside ViewModels.

As to the `getApplicationContext().getString()`, create an interface for this. Something like:

```
interface StringProvider {
    String getString(int resource);
}
```

Then pass that interface in your ViewModel constructor and use that to get the string you want.

When you initialize the ViewModel, you can pass a concrete implementation of `StringProvider` like this:

```
class StringProviderImpl implements StringProvider {
     String getString(int resource) {
        return SampleApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getString(resource);
     }
}
```

This way, for your unit tests, you can just mock `StringProvider` and don't have to worry about dealing with contexts inside your ViewModel and the related test code.

Comment: In this example, is the ViewModel class StringProviderImpl?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test the `String.format` method.  That is not your code, and your goal should be to test your own code. But your code is using that method, so you need to test your code. This is the part you are trying to validate or mock out as I understand it:

```
String.format(SampleApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.due), SampleApp.getInstance().getAccountManager().getBillingDueDate())
```

which makes several calls to SampleApp to get an instance.  Since those calls to SampleApp.getInstance are static method calls, you won't be able to mock them out.  There isn't enough code posted to know what SampleApp is or what `SampleApp.getInstance()` returns  or to know if any of the subsequent calls on that instance are returning null, but one of them is.  So I think to solve this you need to look at the what the getInstance method returns.  If you can't touch that code and you're hoping to *only* modify your test classes, you may not be able to test this with mockito due to the static method.

But otherwise you will need to build a way for your tests so the call to `SampleApp.getInstance` returns a *mock* object as the instance instead of whatever real instance I presume it is returning now.  Then you can mock out the subsequent methods like getApplicationContext and getString to make them return canned responses so that the `string.format` call will not fail on a null input.

One note of caution--if you do end up making the static getInstance method return a mock, but sure you have proper cleanup when your test is done to set it back to what it was returning originally so you don't inadvertently modify something that might cause another unrelated unit test to fail.  That is always a risk if you change something returned by a static method in a unit test since you are effectively changing it for *all* tests.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the test fails after the `AccountManager` was already used, you should have set up the `SampleApp` as a mock or fake already.

```
SampleApp app = SampleApp.getInstance()
AccountManager am = app.getAccountManager();
Context context = app.getApplicationContext();
billDate.set(!TextUtils.isEmpty(am.getDueDate()) ?
    String.format(context.getString(R.string.due), am.getBillingDueDate()) :
    context.getString(R.string.missing_due_date);
```

Now you only need to make sure to mock the `Context` you provide with with `app.getApplicationContext()` or the `SampleApp` itself, if you use `app.getString()` directly.

```
doReturn(dueFormatString).when(context).getString(R.string.due);
doReturn(dueMissingString).when(context).getString(R.string.missing_due_date);
```

But in general you should abstract the `Context` away. Not using it will simplify your code and therefore your testing a lot.

Also consider using `context.getString()` instead of `String.format()` for formatting a string you load from a resource. It's as easy as adding the format arguments as parameters to the call.

```
context.getString(R.string.due, am.getBillingDueDate())
```